# How to find out if style is present in a class by Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I tried to google out "jquery function to return object with css properties of the class" but I did not found valuable results.

Let's suppose in a DOM I have a div node with className = "A B C".
I have valid Jquery object called "search" which contains html element. I need to find out if it contains some styles and values and in case that they I found I will perform an action (remove the class from node.className)

```
var search = $("div.A");
var css_arr = search.prop("className").split(" ");
```

Here are conditions for the styles to be tested:

```
float != "none" or Float != "" -> if yes, remove the class
position != "absolute" or position != "" -> if yes, remove the class
left is present ... remove the class -> if yes, remove the class
top is present ... remove the class -> if yes, remove the class
```

My questions are **how to perform the test?**

**Is there function in JQuery to return object with css properties of specified class?**

Live example:
http://kod.djpw.cz/gwac

**Edit:**
I have started to work in the code based on reading of sheet object.

```
cssList = function(node) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    var sheet;
    for (var i in sheets) {
      if ( sheets[i].hasOwnProperty('cssRules') )
        sheet = sheets[i].cssRules;
      else
      if ( sheets[i].hasOwnProperty('rules') )
        sheet = sheets[i].rules;
      else
        continue;

      var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
      for (var r in rules) {
          if (node.is(rules[r].selectorText)) 
            {
              o = $.extend(o, make_it_easy.easy.css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(node.attr('style')));
            }
        }  

    }
    return o;
}
```

Problem here: `sheets[i].hasOwnProperty('cssRules')` or `sheets[i].hasOwnProperty('rules')` always returns false. Why? In debugger I see the cssRules property but I cannot check if it exists.

Comment: You can get the style using window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('float'). Sorry can't answer. I don't know how to use jQuery.

Comment: In css you can use right: value to specify element position from right edge of the html document. But the word right is not in the DOM. In the node there is top and left. So I think I cannot use computed styles for this. It should be taken from css.

Comment: Create fiddle so we can see.

Comment: OK, here it is: http://kod.djpw.cz/gwac

Comment: are you want to replace or remove class after find it ?

Comment: I don't think what your planning will result to a proper solution. See this example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgYymE.
It only reads the first class, and same class can have different styles for different elements.

Comment: @JaredT Edit. of course you can read all classes, but styles can all be different...

Comment: @JaredT: IDK how to refresh the console in codepen.io ...

Comment: @user1141649, there is a clear on the side. You also just use your browser's dev tool console...

Comment: @user1141649, save then refresh/f5 mate.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's cloned elements are getting default styles and we can use it this way:

```js
$.fn.extend({
    removeClassWithStyles: function(properties) {
        function filterClasses(child, cloned) {
            var thisClassAttr = child.attr("class");
            if (thisClassAttr) {
                var splitClassName = thisClassAttr.split(/\s+/);
                $.each(splitClassName, function(c, className) {
                    cloned.removeClass(className);
                    $.each(properties, function(p, prop) {
                        if (child.css(prop) != cloned.css(prop)) {
                            console.log('remove class: ' + className);
                            child.removeClass(className);
                            return false;
                        };
                    });
                });
            };

        };
        return this.each(function() {
            var thisElement = $(this);
            thisElement.find('*').each(function(e) {
                var child = $(this);
                var cloned = $(this).clone();
                filterClasses(child, cloned);
            });
        });
    }
});
$('body').removeClassWithStyles([
    'float', 'position', 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'
]);
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right-abs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 100px;
}
.top-abs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div class="right-abs top-abs center">
    <h3>World</h3>
</div>
```

Also on **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppv48e0w/)**

**Explanation:**

We are comparing elements styles to default browser style, therefore we know if those are changed by specific class or not.

Comment: Each element in document gets default styles after the browser renders it. Elements that have styles added will be different from default ones. Using jQuerys [clone method](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) we create new element with default styles (because it is not inserted in DOM tree) and compare them to original - if those two differ, than we remove the class that made the change. Hope you understand it better now.

Comment: I have analysed your code and I have found that it only removes the classes when they are inserted (not part of the stylesheet).

Comment: In your question you said: "Let's suppose in a DOM I have a div node with className = "A B C" and you want to remove classes which make element to float, or set element's position. For your question you got the correct answer. If you also want to set new styles, it won't be difficult.

Comment: what if the elements have inline styles like this: `<div id="element_id" class="element_class" styles="position:relative; left: 20px ">` ... I think your code will fail when element_class contains position:relative and inline style is also position:relative. Because the element.css("position") will return "relative" and cloned.css("position") will also return "relative". No difference -> program thinks the rule is not in the class. ... I think you have mistake near `cloned.removeClass`. You should pass var cloned = $(element).clone(); before it. U want to detect if attribute ain't in class.

Comment: I understand that element_style !== cloned_style means the class was calculated. But what if the condition is false? Does this mean that I need to search stylesheets to find out the default class? Or the .css method did this for me? I think css checks only the inline styles or the styles which are result. Also to perform stylesheets check would not be reliable because I cannot know the correct priority of the rules. E.g. Some class "xy" in sheet[0] having position:relative, maybe ovewriten in class "xy" in sheet[2] having position:absolute...

Comment: Ask another question with inline styles or styles set via other elements and I shall be glad to answer that too. The goal would be override external styles. But please note, you asked in this question to remove styles, so I focused on that. One more thing, I am not on exam here, I just try to help you and others. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what your planning will result to a proper solution.

The AAA ID surely has float **right** from class hello, but getting class hello css still gives us **left** even with document ready.

Experiment code below with your way,

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozvzwX?editors=1111

Same class can have different styles for different elements.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var search = $("div#left");
  var class_arr = search.prop("className").split(" ");
  console.log("hello "+class_arr)

  $.each(class_arr,function(){
    console.log($("."+class_arr).css("float"))
    console.log($("#AAA").css("float"))  
    //hello hello
    //left
    //right
  })
})
```

```css
div #left { float: left }
div #right { float: right}
.hello {float:right}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<div id="left" class="hello">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<div id="right" class="hello">
<h3>World</h3>
</div>
  
<div id="AAA" class="hello">
<h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Why not just remove the styles you don't want, you can make it dynamic?

```js
$("#left").css("float","none"); 
$( document ).ready(function(){
      console.log("Final "+$("#left").css("float"))
      //none
    })
```

```css
div #left { float: left }
div #right { float: right}
.hello {float:right}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<div id="left" class="hello">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<div id="right" class="hello">
<h3>World</h3>
</div>
  
<div id="AAA" class="hello">
<h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I need to find out which styles I don't want first. You could say: Well, I want to remove a class. But how will you recognise that some particular class you want to remove? You need to analyse the content of the class... or as skobaljic said to compair if the default styles has been changed, seemed as been solution too, maybe. Still working and thinking about the problem

Comment: Your sole purpose of removing class is to prevent certain styles from taking over? Is this correct?

Comment: Classes does not hold styles, elements does. An element can get styles from other sources and not just classes, e.g. from my first example. So I don't think you can properly rely on it.

Comment: It is for particular situation where a common habit is to use either classes or ids. No reason to import styles or create new classes by Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the scobaljic advice I have made this code. scobaljic code contained some mistakes which I have corrected. And my goal was not to look for nested elements. I have also added a function to check for ids. The key thing here is backup of the inline styles, to remove them from element before comparison and restore them after comparison. I am still debugging the code, so it may change in the future to fix bugs.

```
/* Remove classes and ids with unwanted styles */
$.fn.extend({
removeClassWithStyles: function(properties, collectWidthAndPadding = false) 
  {
  paddingAttribs = ["padding", "padding-left", "padding-right"];
  widthAttribs = ["width", "max-width"];
  heightAttribs = ["height", "max-height"];

  function checkObjectProp( obj, element )
  {
    return ( obj.prop == "float" && obj.exclude 
       && 
       (
       obj.exclude == element.css( obj.prop ) 
       )
     ) ? true : false;
  }

  function remove_attr( properties, element, backupObj )
  {
  backupObj;
  for (var p in properties)
    {
    if ( typeof properties[p] === 'object' )
      {
      backupObj.attr.push(properties[p].prop);      
      backupObj.val.push( element.css(properties[p].prop) );
      element.css(properties[p].prop,"");
      }
    else
      {      
      backupObj.attr.push(properties[p]);      
      backupObj.val.push( element.css(properties[p]) );
      element.css(properties[p],"");
      }
    }
  }

  function restore_attr( properties, element, backupObj )
  {
  for (var p in backupObj.attr)
     element.css(backupObj.attr[p], backupObj.val[p]);
  backupObj = { attr: [], val: [] } // reset
  }

  /*
  To detect classes rules and ids rules
  I need to create copy of the original
  element or to backup the inline styles.
  I choosed to backup the inline styles
  because it is faster then clone.
  After I inline styles, I will create 
  clone of the element and compare the
  styles with the modified element.
  Then I restore the styles.
  */
  function filterClasses(element, className, id) 
  {
  if ( className )
    {
    var class_contains_width = false;
    var class_contains_height = false;
    element.css("position", "relative");    
    element.css("float", "left");

    $.each( className.split(/\s+/),
      function(c, className) 
      {
      /* 
      Find out if current class 
      contains the style
      */
      var cloned = $(element).clone();


      // remove class
      cloned.removeClass(className);

      /* Detect padding in element or clone */
      if ( collectWidthAndPadding && cloned.checkPropertiesPresent(element, paddingAttribs) )
        search_padding_collection_classes = search_padding_collection_classes.add(element);            
      /* Detect if width/height could be removed with a class
         + prevent from calling multiple times
         */
      if ( collectWidthAndPadding && !class_contains_width && search_width_classes && cloned.checkPropertiesPresent(element, widthAttribs) )
        search_width_classes = search_width_classes.add(element);
      // div#BlogArchive1 div.widget-content

      $.each(properties, function(p, prop) 
        {
        /* Then remove classes */
        if ( typeof prop === 'object' )
          {
          // A) The style has been inserted
          if ( element.css(prop.prop) != cloned.css(prop.prop) )
            {
            if ( checkObjectProp( prop, cloned ) )
              { // skip it
              }
            else
              {
              // element.removeClass(className);
              return false;
              }              
            }
          else // B) The style has not been inserted
            {
            if (element.css(prop))
              if ( checkObjectProp( prop, element ) )
                { // skip it
                }
              else
                {
                // element.removeClass(className);
                return false;
                }              
            }
          }
        else // prop is not object
          {
          // A) The style has been inserted
          // element.css("right") != cloned.css("right")
          if (element.css(prop) != cloned.css(prop))
            {
            // element.removeClass(className);
            return false;
            }
          else // B) The style has not been inserted
            {
            if (element.css(prop))
              {
              // element.removeClass(className);
              return false;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    };
  };
  function filterIds(element, className, id) 
  {
  if ( id )
    {
    /* 
    Find out if current id 
    contains the style
    */
    var cloned = $(element).clone();
    // remove id    
    cloned.removeAttr("id");

    /* Detect padding in element or clone */
    if ( collectWidthAndPadding && cloned.checkPropertiesPresent(element, paddingAttribs) )
      search_padding_collection_classes = search_padding_collection_classes.add(element);            
    /* Detect if width/height could be removed with a class
       + prevent from calling multiple times
       */
    if ( collectWidthAndPadding && search_width_ids && cloned.checkPropertiesPresent(element, widthAttribs) )
      search_width_ids = search_width_ids.add(element);
    // div#BlogArchive1 div.widget-content

    $.each(properties, function(p, prop) 
      {
      /* Then remove classes */
      if ( typeof prop === 'object' )
        {
        // A) The style has been inserted
        if ( element.css(prop.prop) != cloned.css(prop.prop) )
          {
          if ( checkObjectProp( prop, cloned ) )
            { // skip it
            }
          else
            {
            // element.removeAttr("id");
            return false;
            }              
          }
        else // B) The style has not been inserted
          {
          if (element.css(prop))
            if ( checkObjectProp( prop, element ) )
              { // skip it
              }
            else
              {
              // element.removeAttr("id");
              return false;
              }              
          }
        }
      else // prop is not object
        {
        // A) The style has been inserted
        // element.css("right") != cloned.css("right")
        if (element.css(prop) != cloned.css(prop))
          {
          // element.removeAttr("id");
          return false;
          }
        else // B) The style has not been inserted
          {
          if (element.css(prop))
            {
            // element.removeAttr("id");
            return false;
            }
          }
        }
      });
    };
  };

  return function(element){
    var className = element.attr("class");
    var id = element.attr("id");    
    var backup_inline_styles = { attr: [], val: [] }
    if ( className || id )
      { 
      remove_attr( properties, element, backup_inline_styles );
      }
    filterClasses(element,className,id);
    filterIds(element,className,id);
    if ( className || id )
      restore_attr( properties, element, backup_inline_styles );
  }($(this))

  }
});
```

Implementation

```
window.onload = function() {  
  search_padding_collection_classes = $();
  search_width_classes = $();
  search_padding_collection_ids = $();
  search_width_ids = $();
  var search = $("div.column-right-outer");
  $(search).removeClassWithStyles([ { prop: 'float', exclude: 'none' }, 'position', 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left' ], true);
  $(search).compressElementsWidth();
  // console.log($('div.column-right-outer').find("*").filter(":visible"));
};
```